# Searching for password in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am searching for password in a text file but it says password not found every time, although the passwords exist in the file.

This is my current code:

```
 import pickle
 import time      
    print "Do you already have a database created"
    y=raw_input("'yes' to continue")
    if y=='yes':               #to search password in text file
      infile=open(r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\itika study material\cs\password.txt", "r") 
      Passwords = infile.readlines()

      while True:
        InputPassword = raw_input("Enter your password.")
        print "Searching for password."
        time.sleep(2)
        if InputPassword in Passwords:
            print "your password has been found, you can access your database"
            break
        else:
            print "your password has Not been found."    #only prints this statement
            break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your indentation looks of (2 spaces ↔ 4 spaces).

Comment: I know this sounds like "Ok, man, good stuff", but... try to not store passwords in the clear.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that your `Passwords` variable contains a newline and your `InputPassword` array does not. Try looking at them in a debugger with a very simple set to confirm there is an exact match. Remember there has to be an exact match for the `in` function to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Passwords = infile.read()` instead of `Passwords = infile.readlines()`. This reads the whole file and lets you search the `InputPassword` string in the whole file.

Please be aware, that this is not a secure check for a password.

Answer (score 0):

The list which is created in "Passwords" variable has "\n" in it.
just strip the \n and it should work fine

Here's the correct:

```
import pickle
import time
print("Do you already have a database created")
y = input("'yes' to continue")
if y == 'yes':  # to search password in text file
    Passwords = list(
        map(lambda x: x.strip(), (open(r"password.txt", "r")).readlines()))

    # Passwords = "infile"
    print(type(Passwords))
    print(Passwords)

    while True:
        InputPassword = input("Enter your password.")
        print("Searching for password: ", end=" ")
        print(InputPassword)
        time.sleep(2)
        if InputPassword in Passwords:
            print("your password has been found, you can access your database")
            break
        else:
            print("your password has Not been found.")
            break
```